# How did 'rejoin' semantically shift to mean 'answer to a legal charge'?

Tags: discussion

Pourquoi clore [How did 're' + 'joindre' semantically shift to mean 'answer to a legal charge'?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40540/1995) comme hors sujet?

> does not appear to be about French language within the scope defined in the [help center](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Je véritablement demande l'Ancien et le Moyen Fr; re + joindre and rejoindre ne sont pas les verbes anglais.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because it was unclear that you were actually asking a question about Middle French. I'd support reopening if

1. You make it clearer what you are actually asking
2. What you are actually asking is a question about Middle French

If it is the case, we don't really need the context you gave about English, except maybe as a side note. Make sure you also use the proper tag [moyen-français].